# Docusign - FLOW - REST API

Tags: docusignapi

I ran into an issue with DocuSign – HTTP connector in Flow, Calling Rest API. It totally works with sandbox DocuSign Account, but failing with Production account.

What am I missing?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`account.docusign.com` is the API endpoint for authentication calls only: you can make a call to request a token, or to get a token's [UserInfo](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/user-info-endpoints). In order to make API calls against the eSignature API, you need to make them against an application server endpoint.

To find your account's application server endpoint while using Legacy Header authentication, you need to make a call to GET `https://www.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information`. This call will return a BaseUrl value for your account: something like `na3.docusign.net` or `ca.docusign.net`, but there are several possible server environments.

Once you know the base URL for an account you can cache it indefinitely - account's don't move between servers except upon request in very specific circumstances.